# What is coming inside the IMPACT area on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that there is extra space in the IMPACT area above the *"posts edited"* field. See:

[image]

Is there a new feature coming in the red box?

Comment: I doubt it. Looks more like the CMs are messing with the stylesheet to me.

Comment: Could just be white space, to separate the concept of "Impact" from that of "things you have done".

Comment: probably the impact of John Skeet takes two lines

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's unlikely - one line is more than enough to state "all people reached"

Comment: @gnat nope you are wrong, John Skeet can reach more than *all the people*.

Comment: Advertising ...

Comment: There is a point to [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775).

Comment: It looks like its made to align with the *Reputation* and *Badges* sections.

Comment: @TemaniAfif it only takes one line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzYmD.png

Comment: I think it's because the Impact is top-aligned, and the rest are bottom-aligned, and the box grows (and shrinks) with the other boxes in that section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ42L.png

Comment: hence the moral of discussion is: there is nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -6):

Look, the tooltip fits perfectly in the box. If the box was smaller, it wouldn't fit. I suggest it's by design.

[image]

Comment: Not in my case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qk0C.png

Comment: @astonearachnid, That doesn't mean my "by design" assertion is incorrect. It just means it's poorly implemented :).

Comment: For me it's perfect on the Main User profile but not on meta.  I think @jpp may be on to something, personally.